# Re-arrange letters on phone keyboard

Tags: phone

I'm using a Swedish keyboard on Ubuntu phone. Two of the letters are in the wrong place, "ä" and "ö". Can I change this myself?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been reported as bug under https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-keyboard/+bug/1395402, where it says as well that it has been fixed in the package ubuntu-keyboard - 0.99.trunk.phablet2+15.10.20150529-0ubuntu1